# How to find Max value of a column using self join in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join, self-join

The question is:
Find the printer models having the highest price. Result set: model, price

And the DB schema is:
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)

I want to find the highest price using the self join.The query written by me is:

```
select model,price
from printer
where not exists
(
select p2.model,p2.price
    from printer p1, printer p2
    where p2.price<p1.price
)
```

The subquery seems to be correct as it does not include the highest but the whole query is giving empty table.
Link of the question is : http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref

Comment: How many printer models do you want to see? If just one, why not `SELECT model, price FROM printer ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't written your correlated subquery correctly. You need to reference back to the table you are reading from (i.e. the outer query), not include it again in the subquery:

```
SELECT model, price
FROM printer p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM printer p2 WHERE p2.price > p1.price)
```

Note that this is not a self-join, this is a correlated subquery. To write this function using a self-join, use a `LEFT JOIN` and check that the value in the join table is `NULL`:

```
SELECT p1.model, p1.price
FROM printer p1
LEFT JOIN printer p2 ON p2.price > p1.price
WHERE p2.model IS NULL
```

Note also that as @kmoser points out in the comments, you can do this more simply using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT model, price
FROM printer 
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wrTvugaKF8ofhG6wSRGJnA/1) of all three queries on SQLFiddle.